# Error subtracting floating point numbers when passing through 0.0

Tags: c++, c, floating-point, rounding-error

The following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    double val = 1.0;
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        val -= 0.2;
        printf("%g %s\n", val, (val == 0.0 ? "zero" : "non-zero"));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Produces this output:

```
0.8 non-zero
0.6 non-zero
0.4 non-zero
0.2 non-zero
5.55112e-17 non-zero
-0.2 non-zero
-0.4 non-zero
-0.6 non-zero
-0.8 non-zero
-1 non-zero
```

Can anyone tell me what is causing the error when subtracting 0.2 from 0.2?  Is this a rounding error or something else?  Most importantly, how do I avoid this error?

EDIT: It looks like the conclusion is to not worry about it, given 5.55112e-17 is extremely close to zero (thanks to @therefromhere for that information).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its because floating points numbers can not be stored in memory in exact value. So it is never safe to use `==` in floating point values. Using double will increase the precision, but again that will not be exact. The correct way to compare a floating point value is to do something like this:

```
val == target;   // not safe

// instead do this
// where EPS is some suitable low value like 1e-7
fabs(val - target) < EPS;
```

EDIT: As pointed in the comments, the main reason of the problem is that 0.2 can't be stored exactly. So when you are subtracting it from some value, every time causing some error. If you do this kind of floating point calculation repeatedly then at certain point the error will be noticeable. What I am trying to say is that all floating points values can't be stored, as there are infinites of them. A slight wrong value is not generally noticeable but using that is successive computation will lead to higher cumulative error.

Comment: I'm not worried about the 'non-zero' message being produced, what worries me is that getting 5.55112e-17 instead of 0.0 is more than just a rounding error isn't it?

Comment: This is because the computer can't store 0.0. The nearest value of zero that it can store in this case is 5.55112e-17. And that value can be varied from compiler to compiler, hardware to hardware.

Comment: @trojanfoe: 5.55112e-17 = 5.55112 * 10 to the power of -17.  This is *extremely* close to zero.

Comment: of course the machine can store 0 exactly. It's the intermediate numbers on the way to 0 that can't be stored

Comment: @taskinoor: an IEEE FP-compliant processor can surely store 0.

Comment: I agree that saying it can not store 0.0 exactly it technically wrong, but that is the easiest explanation that I have found. What I am trying to say is that it cannot store all floating point values. So when we right something 3.14159 then it may not be exactly equal to that.

Comment: And when subtracting 0.2, it may not be equal to 0.2 exactly which is causing the problem.

Comment: @therefromhere: That is interesting.  Can I just ignore it if it's that close to zero?

Comment: @taskinoor: An explanation doesn't become valid just because it is easy.  In fact the problem is that 0.2 cannot be stored exactly in a float or double and the slight inexactness is cumulative when you repeatedly subtract it from 10.

Comment: @JeremyP, again agree. I have edited my answer. I should have written that before.

Comment: @taskinoor: I didn't notice a problem with your answer, I was responding to the comment. Anyway, +1 for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

0.2 is not a double precision floating-point number, so it is rounded to the nearest double precision number, which is:

```
            0.200000000000000011102230246251565404236316680908203125
```

That's rather unwieldy, so let's look at it in hex instead:

```
          0x0.33333333333334
```

Now, let's follow what happens when this value is repeatedly subtracted from 1.0:

```
          0x1.00000000000000
        - 0x0.33333333333334
        --------------------
          0x0.cccccccccccccc
```

The exact result is not representable in double precision, so it is rounded, which gives:

```
          0x0.ccccccccccccd
```

In decimal, this is exactly:

```
            0.8000000000000000444089209850062616169452667236328125
```

---

Now we repeat the process:

```
          0x0.ccccccccccccd
        - 0x0.33333333333334
        --------------------
          0x0.9999999999999c
rounds to 0x0.999999999999a
           (0.600000000000000088817841970012523233890533447265625 in decimal)

          0x0.999999999999a
        - 0x0.33333333333334
        --------------------
          0x0.6666666666666c
rounds to 0x0.6666666666666c
           (0.400000000000000077715611723760957829654216766357421875 in decimal)

          0x0.6666666666666c
        - 0x0.33333333333334
        --------------------
          0x0.33333333333338
rounds to 0x0.33333333333338
           (0.20000000000000006661338147750939242541790008544921875 in decimal)

          0x0.33333333333338
        - 0x0.33333333333334
        --------------------
          0x0.00000000000004
rounds to 0x0.00000000000004
           (0.000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625 in decimal)
```

Thus, we see that the accumulated rounding that is required by floating-point arithmetic produces the very small **non-zero** result that you are observing.  Rounding is subtle, but it is deterministic, not magic, and not a bug.  It's worth taking the time to learn about.

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate a bit: if the mantissa of the floating point number is encoded in binary (as is the case in most contemporary FPUs), then only sums of (multiples) of the numbers 1/2, 1/4, 1/8, 1/16, ... can be represented exactly in the mantissa. The value 0.2 is approximated with 1/8 + 1/16 + .... some even smaller numbers, yet the exact value of 0.2 can not be reached with a finite mantissa.

You can try the following:

```
 printf("%.20f", 0.2);
```

and you'll (probably) see that what you think is 0.2 is not 0.2 but a number that is a tiny amount different (actually, on my computer it prints 0.20000000000000001110). Now you understand why you can never reach 0.

But if you let val = 12.5 and subtract 0.125 in your loop, you could reach zero.

Answer (score 1):

Floating point arithmetic cannot represent all numbers exactly. Thus rounding errors like you observe are inevitable.

One possible strategy is to use a fixed point format, e.g. A decimal or currency data type. Such types still can't represent all numbers but would behave as you expect for this example.